# Parse.com FindAsync query stops

Tags: c#, parse-platform, xamarin

I have what I thought should be a simple thing to do. I am using Xamarin and code is C#. I have set up some simple tests to get data from my Parse account. I have been able to add data and select a single item from parse but now I want to get all, currently about 30 items, from a table. For some reason though the code never reaches the "assert" statements. After it does the "query.FindAsync()" code it just stops. It did work one time and it took a while and I am not sure exactly why it worked and now will not. I could be missing something or using async/await incorrectly here? Thanks for any tips!

```
[Test]
public async void GetItems()
{
    ParseClient.Initialize("myapikey", "my.netkey");
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("ClassName");
    IEnumerable<ParseObject> result = await query.FindAsync();

    Assert.NotNull(result);
    Assert.IsTrue(result.Count() > 1);
}
```

Comment: How do you invoke this test?

Comment: When you say it *"stops"* do you mean it just doesn't reach the assert statements or it freezes? If it's freezing then it could be a result of a deadlock - it's actually a common problem using async / await in ASP.NET (however, not sure if the same would apply here)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - I created a NUnit test project in Xamarin and run the test through an Emulator. This is currently the only code I have that runs in the test.

Comment: NUnit in Xamarin doesn't handle async unit tests correctly... I took a break from fighting with this exact issue this morning to peruse stackoverflow and found this question.

Comment: @James - It never reaches the assert statements, but in the emulator it does display that the test passed so I am not sure how that happens. I put a breakpoint on the FindAsync call and the Assert.NotNull and after the FindAsync call it does not stop on the Assert.Not null breakpoint. It does seem like a freeze or a deadlock to me but I don't know for sure why.

Comment: @RexM The thing is though it works with my insert/update/delete tests just fine.

Comment: This is a long shot and probably wont help, but try changing the return type to `async Task` instead of `async void`.

Comment: Returning `Task` would make sense, but Xamarin's NUnit test runner currently skips non-void tests :(

Comment: Thanks @YuvalItzchakov, but Rex is correct it just skips the test.

Comment: @RexM Seriously? that sounds peculiar. Making programmers write bad code just to make unit tests work.

Comment: Where I am using this in my actual code project it Returns "Task" but doesn't work either. I put it into a test to narrow down the code to try to figure out the issue.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov agreed, it's very frustrating. I've been looking at possible solutions for a few hours now. One of the ugliest, but easiest to manage, potential solutions is to use [Stephen Cleary's AsyncEx library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx) to wrap the body of each unit test.

Comment: @AndrewMallonee in your 'actual project code', when you say it 'doesn't work' do you mean it is deadlocking (i.e. the program is still running but halts on the expected line)?

Comment: Yes, it seems like "deadlock" is the most likely issue in the actual project code

Comment: In the project have you tried `await query.FindAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)`?

Comment: Looks like this was a [bug](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14175/deadlock-in-nunit-test) with NUnit but was fixed.

Comment: @James I don't think it was fixed (at least not for all cases), since the behavior is still simple to reproduce in the latest version of Xamarin.

Comment: @RexM I will try that when I can, but I updated Xamarin just now and am getting an error with MonoPackageManager.java. smh so I will have to figure that out first.

Comment: It is getting data now after I updated Xamarin. Doesn't make much sense though. There has to be another reason why it wasn't working but it is working now. It does take almost 30 seconds to return the results though.

Comment: Well it's most likely fixed because you have updated to a version that contains the fix?

Comment: It is still "buggy" in my actual project though. Sometimes it works and sometimes it seems to lock up.

Comment: @AndrewMallonee if you can reproduce it then I suggest you post it over on the Xamarin forums - however, I would say this is more of an issue with how async / await works rather than a Xamarin "bug"